# DeploymentManagerCreationException

Tags: java, weblogic

When I run the following code in command window

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl localhost:7001 -user weblogic -password weblogic -start -name myTestDeployment"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.DeploymentManagerCreationException at   
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(W  
ebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:121) at     
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.factories.internal.DeploymentFactoryImpl.getD 
eploymentManager(DeploymentFactoryImpl.java:84) at     
weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.getDeploymentManager(SessionH elper.java:432) at     
weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.connect(Jsr88Operat ion.java:304) at 
weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:137 ) at   
weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:88) at   
weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158) at 
weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115) at   
weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:70)   at weblogic.Deployer.main(Deployer.java:54)   
Caused by: weblogic.deploy.api.spi.exceptions.ServerConnectionException at   
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.init(Ser   
verConnectionImpl.java:143) at   
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewCo   
nnection(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:148) at   
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(W   
ebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:118) ... 9 more Caused by:   
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.Conne ctException:   
localhost:7001: Destination unreachable; nested exception is : java.net.ConnectException:  
 Connection refused: connect; No available rou ter to destination] at 



weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(Exceptio nTranslator.java:40)  
 at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLIni   
tialContextFactoryDelegate.java:773) at   
weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLIni   
tialContextFactoryDelegate.java:363) at   
weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:307) at   
weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:277) at   
weblogic.jndi.Environment.createInitialContext(Environment.java:200) at   
weblogic.jndi.Environment.getInitialContext(Environment.java:184) at   
weblogic.jndi.Environment.getInitialContext(Environment.java:162) at   
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getConte   
xt(ServerConnectionImpl.java:330) at   
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvir   
onment(ServerConnectionImpl.java:302) at   
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.init(Ser   
verConnectionImpl.java:141) ... 11 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException:  
 localhost:7001: Destination unreach able; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException:  
 Connection refused: connect; No available rou ter to destination at   
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:204) at   
weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:154) at   
weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate$1.run(WLInitialContextF   
actoryDelegate.java:342) at   
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate dSubject.java:363)  
 at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source) at   
weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLIni   
tialContextFactoryDelegate.java:337) ... 19 more Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException:   
Destination unreachable; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection   
refused: connect; No available rou ter to destination at   
weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:472) at   
weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:323) at   
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java :263) at   
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:206) at   
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:226 ) at   
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteCluster(RJVMFinder.java:30 8) at   
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:194) ... 24 more Unable to connect  
 to 'localhost:7001': Destination unreachable; nested ex ception is:   
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; No available rou ter to   
destination. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that th e credentials  
 are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If you have installed weblogic with default ports, then you do not need to set the adminurl parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the admin server is running on this server port 7001:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.Conne ctException:   
localhost:7001: Destination unreachable; nested exception is : java.net.ConnectException:  
 Connection refused: connect; No available rou ter to destination]
```